# Determining Serial port usage

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I want to programmaticaly check for the available serial ports which are not connected with any device.

i tried the following code and able to get the available com ports but dont know whether it is used. how to determine that?

```
TCHAR szComPort[8];  
HANDLE hCom = NULL;  

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)  
{  
    if (i < 10)
      wsprintf(szComPort, _T("COM%d"), i);
    else
      wsprintf(szComPort, _T("\\\\.\\COM%d"), i); 

    hCom = CreateFile(szComPort,  
        GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, // desired access should be read&write  
        0,                          // COM port must be opened in non-sharing mode  
        NULL,                       // don't care about the security  
        OPEN_EXISTING,              // IMPORTANT: must use OPEN_EXISTING for a COM port  
        0,                          // usually overlapped but non-overlapped for existance test  
        NULL);                      // always NULL for a general purpose COM port  

   }
```

Comment: You have two issues to work out: 1) What method will you use to tell if a serial port is connected to a device? 2) What code will you use to implement that method? There is no one right answer to the first question, it depends on your outer problem, which you don't mention.

Comment: It doesn't stop at 10.  Looking for unconnected ports is pretty pointless.  They'll never do anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike USB, there's no reliable method to check whether a serial (RS232) port is connected. It's quite common to use just TD, RD and ground (transmit/receive). Even when other pins are connected, their use isn't well standardized.